# PhoneGap Location Based App and Portibility

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, cordova, blackberry

I have built apps for android using PhoneGap and have had no issues at all. Today I got a requirement to build an app that runs on android, iphone, windows mobiles phones, blackberry ( old and new he said - whats with that? ). So my question is are there any issues, hickups when building an app for all these platforms that uses location based data with phonegap? Like are there any sort of issues I could get into and should take in consideration before I take up such a project.

Also any ideas about how could I test such an app as I do not have anything besides an android device do it would cost me a lot to buy these devices to test my app.

About the app: The app is a simple app that is supposed to find the closest 'x' to you.

Thanking you

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is just sending location when your application is active, you can very well use [HTML5 Geolocation](http://html5demos.com/geo). However if you need to continuously track the location, probably as a background service or something, you may have to go with plugins. Regarding the cost involved in iPhone development, I think you require some kind of developer license to test it on apple device. Not very sure about it though!

Answer (score 2):

I think by old and new Blackberry, the client means maybe BB7/8 and BB10; I'm pretty sure that the way you build apps is different between them, with BB10 using WebWorks (first class HTML5). Cordova supports BB10 for sure and probably the old versions as well, at least partially.

You can try using the [Ripple emulator](http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/) to test the other devices that you don't have, however, I personally would try to borrow devices from friends or something to test at least once before releasing it into production.

Cordova (aka Phonegap) does have a [GeoLocation API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation) and it has support for:

```
    Android
    BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 5.0 and higher)
    iOS
    Windows Phone 7 and 8
    Bada 1.2 & 2.x
    webOS
    Tizen
    Windows 8
```

Often times the Cordova implementation will just fall back on the HTML5 Geolocation, but for the platforms that don't support that, it will use the native Geolocation functionality.

I have heard of issues with accuracy when doing a "watch" type of application, like a run tracker app, however if you just want to get the location and geocode it to find the nearest businesses near you, that should definitely be easy in Cordova.

Yes you will need to purchase a $100/year license from Apple to publish your app on the app store, and a $25/year license from Google for Android. I don't know about the other systems.